# How can I make sure all implicit parameters that normally are in scope in a running Play (scala) app are also available from the Play Console?

Tags: scala, playframework

There is a Play implicit value Request:

```
implicit req: Request[_] = ...
```

which is used in the Play app.

I need access to it on the console to experiment with the templates and get quick output. How can I make sure that all implicits which would be normally in-scope during the running of the app are also in-scope on the console?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How can a request be available from console? Which HTTP request should it be related to?

Comment: sorry, good point, there isn't a way to fake it somehow? A test env?

Comment: You can fake it in a unit test, but I don't how to do that in the console. http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaFunctionalTest